# Display fn keys by default in Touch Bar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

I would like to configure the Touch Bar of my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016) to display by default the static fn keys (esc, F1, F2, ...) all the time, since they are the keys I use the most.

For now, I only managed to configure the touchbar to be static selecting the 'Expanded Control Strip' option (in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard), so it shows the esc, brightness, mission control, etc.

Is there any workaround to do that yet? Running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts, under Function Keys, add apps to the list to show the function keys by default. The fn key will then be used for the inverse function, hiding the function row instead of showing it. You'll need to do this for every app where you would like this behaviour.

You can display function keys at all times and use Fn to display App Controls or Expand Control Strip in System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard.

[image]

Comment: It's a shame that Apple didn't care to provide backwards compatibility for those users (like myself) that previously had configured the Fn key to enable the multimedia, bright, etc. keys, keeping the Function keys as the default **for every single application**...why do I have to do this for every single app I use??? It's just idiotic!

Comment: @Clint You *don't* need to do this for every app, the global setting is still there, see edit

Comment: That's true only if you're using High Sierra. In Sierra, the option's not there. Upgrade? I can't, my company won't allow that... :-(